# Print struts anchor tag

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am printing a datatable, from a JSON retrieved via AJAX. Per each row of the data table print some links to delete or update the associated entity at the row.

Now, how i can print an anchor, where the href attribute reference to my action method with the entity id as parameter ?

I try printing with Javascript:

```
<s:a theme="simple" href="/Infopool/dashboard/events/update"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a><s:param name="id" value=' + row.id +'/></s:a>
```

But, as the code is executed in the client side, my workaround not work.

Any ideas of how can do this ?

Update:

I use a jQuery library (Bootgrid) to render the table with a JSON retrieved via AJAX. The library have a hook to modify the data format. In this case, i try modify the edit link:

```
"actions": function(column, row){
var edit = '<s:a theme="simple" href="/Infopool/dashboard/events/update"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i></a><s:param name="id" value=' + row.id +'/></s:a>';
return edit + " ";
}
```

But a common anchor is printed.

Comment: If you return a JSP snippet, you can include struts tags in the JSP snippet. If you are returning JSON, use javascript in the callback method to alter your generated HTML. For a complete answer, please post the relevant code

Comment: *But a common anchor is printed.* - What do you mean by that? Which one have you expected, a magical one?